# python Can only join an itterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build an async generator like the function below:

```py
async def grab():
    links = ["one", "two"]

    for link in links:
        yield link
```

but when I am trying to use that with a join method like the code below:

```py
grabbedData = "\n ------------------- \n".join(
                link async for link in grab())
```

it gives me error like below:

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I really don't know what is wrong here? am I doing something wrong or it is not possible to use async generator in python join method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link async for link in grab()` is (indeed) not an iterable...

Put square brackets around to make it iterable:

```py
grabbedData = "\n -(...)- \n".join([link async for link in grab()])
```

Full example:

```py
import asyncio

async def grab():
    links = ["one", "two"]

    for link in links:
        yield link

async def main():
    print("\n ------------------- \n".join([link async for link in grab()]))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: @usr2564301 you have to run this code in an async function (as well explained by the syntax error). Here is an example:
https://pastebin.com/dk1j3HvU